# Recursive manipulation of list elements in R

Tags: r, list, recursion

I have a nested list in the global environment of a R script.

```
anno <- list()

anno[['100']] <- list(
    name = "PLACE",
    color = "#a6cee3",
    isDocumentAnnotation = T,
    sublist = list()
)

person_sublist <- list()

person_sublist[['200']] <- list(
  name = "ACTOR",
  color = "#7fc97f",
  isDocumentAnnotation = T,
  sublist = list()
)

person_sublist[['300']] <- list(
  name = "DIRECTOR",
  color = "#beaed4",
  isDocumentAnnotation = T,
  sublist = list()
)

anno[['400']] <- list(
  name = "PERSON",
  color = "#1f78b4",
  isDocumentAnnotation = T,
  sublist = person_sublist
)
```

While running my process I interactively select elements via the id (100,200, ...). In return a want to add, delete or move elements in the list.

For this reason I thought of using a recursive function to navigate through the list:

```
searchListId <- function(parent_id = NULL, annotation_system = NULL)
{
  for(id in names(annotation_system))
  {
    cat(paste(id,"\n"))

    if(id == parent_id)
    {
      return(annotation_system[[id]]$sublist)
    }
    else
    {
      if(length(annotation_system[[id]]$sublist) > 0)
      {
        el <- searchListId(parent_id, annotation_system[[id]]$sublist)
        if(!is.null(el))
          return(el)
      }

    }
  }

  return(NULL)
}

searchListId('100', anno)
```

This functions returns the list() found in the sublist element of the matching element in the 'anno'-list. My problem is the global environment of R. If I manipulate something (**delete, add, move something within the returned sublist**) i need to reset the global variable with `<<-`. But in the case of a recursive function I only hold the current sublist in the context where the parent_id matches. How could one reference a global nested list in R while navigating though it via an recursive function? Is that even possible in R?

The calls I want to carry out in order to delete, add, or move elements in the list 'anno' are:

```
deleteListId('100', anno) #Should return the list without the element 100
addListId('400', anno) #Should return the list with a new element nested in '400'
switchListId('400','200', anno) #Should return a list where the elements with the according keys are switched.
```

The tricky part though is that I don't know how deep the recursive structure is. Normally I would use element references to manipulate them directly but how could a solution for manipulation of nested lists in R look like if I want to use recursion?

Comment: This sounds like a good question but please make your code runnable https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please show data to illustrate your needs. Also, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are describing your *Y* solution but not telling us your fuller *X* problem.

Comment: Please provide a fuller background of your situation as there might be an obvious answer being overlooked. How is nested sublists sourced (i.e., json, xml)? What data does it contain? What are relationships used for add/delete/move logic?

Comment: The X problem is: Editing and manipulating a global nested list in R with recursion.
The Y solution is: Iterate through the nested list with recursion and find/manipulate elements. The missing part in my solution is a way to populate the elements back to the global context. 
This is a standard manipulation pattern for languages like C#, Java etc. but how is this done in R, if even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, have the recursive function take a list, alter that, and return the new version. The reason I suggest this is because it's idiomatic R. R leans toward being a functional language, and part of that means state-based actions are discouraged. In general, functions should only modify state if that's all they do. For example, `scale(x)` doesn't affect the value stored in the `x` variable. But `x <- scale(x)` does, because the `<-` function (yes, it's a function) is meant to modify state.

Also, don't worry about memory unless you *know* it will be a problem based on past experience. Behind the scenes, R is pretty good at preventing needless copying, so trust it to do the right thing. This lets you work with simpler mental models.

A skeleton of how to recursively modify a list, without affecting the original:

```
anno <- list()

anno[['A1']] <- list(
  sublist = list(
    A3 = list(sublist = NULL),
    A4 = list(sublist = list(A6 = list(sublist = NULL))),
    A5 = list(sublist = NULL)
  )
)

change_list <- function(x) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    value <- x[[i]]
    if (is.list(value)) {
      x[[i]] <- change_list(value)
    } else {
      if (is.null(value)) {
        x[[i]] <- "this ws null"
      }
    }
  }
  x
}

change_list(anno)
# $A1
# $A1$sublist
# $A1$sublist$A3
# $A1$sublist$A3$sublist
# [1] "something new"
# 
# 
# $A1$sublist$A4
# $A1$sublist$A4$sublist
# $A1$sublist$A4$sublist$A6
# $A1$sublist$A4$sublist$A6$sublist
# [1] "something new"
# 
# 
# 
# 
# $A1$sublist$A5
# $A1$sublist$A5$sublist
# [1] "something new"
```

If you absolutely need to modify an item in the global namespace, use environments instead of lists.

```
anno_env <- new.env()
anno_env[["A1"]] <- new.env()
anno_env[["A1"]][["sublist"]] <- new.env()
anno_env[["A1"]][["sublist"]][["A3"]] <- NULL
anno_env[["A1"]][["sublist"]][["A4"]] <- NULL

change_environment <- function(environ) {
  for (varname in ls(envir = environ)) {
    value <- environ[[varname]]
    if (is.environment(value)) {
      change_environment(value)
    } else {
      environ[[varname]] <- "something new"
    }
  }
}

change_environment(anno_env)

anno_env[["A1"]][["sublist"]][["A3"]]
# [1] "something new"
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed this strategy fits best into the R language design.

Comment: @Nathan would it please be possible for you to take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58245155/10841085? I'm trying to do something similar but the function I have defined alters the structure of the list. I have tried modifying it several times but to no avail.

Comment: Also, is there a way to suppress the print output of the `change_list` function?